# Playframework, where to put Json Writes and Reads for reuse?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have two controllers who writes and reads the same `AccountModel` case class. This class is an adapter for my "domain" object `Account` who flatten some collections and transform objects references (`Map[Role, Auth]`) to a explicit key reference (`Set[AuthModel(rolekey:String, level:Int)]`).

I would like to reuse this `AccountModel` and his implicits `Writes` and `Reads` but don't know how the achieve that 'the scala way'.

I would say in an `object Models` with my case classes as inner classes and all the related implicits but I think that this would become unreadable soon.

What are you used to do, where do you put your reusable Json classes, do you have some advices ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two main approaches.

**Approach 1: Put them on a companion object of your serializable object:**

```
// in file AccountModel.scala
class AccountModel(...) {
  ...
}

object AccountModel {
  implicit val format: Format[AccountModel] = {...}
}
```

This way everywhere you import `AccountModel`, the formatters will be also available, so everything will work seamlessly.

**Approach 2: Prepare a trait with JSON formatters:**

```
// in a separate file AccountModelJSONSupport.scala
import my.cool.package.AccountModel

trait AccountModelJsonSupport {
  implicit val format: Format[AccountModel] = {...}
}
```

With this approach whenever you need serialization, you have to mix the trait in, like this:

```
object FirstController extends Controller with AccountModelJsonSupport {
  // Format[AccountModel] is available now:
  def create = Action(parse.json[AccountModel]) { ... }
}
```

EDIT: I forgot to add a comparison of the two approaches. I usually stick to approach 1, as it is more straightforward. The `JSONSupport` mixin strategy is however required when you need two different formatters for the same class or when the model class is not your own and you can't modify it. Thanks for pointing it out in the comments.

Comment: Approach 1 is cleaner. The second approach would irk me to no end.

Comment: Yes the second looks like Java where you inherit "Support" classes to have support methods. And it is viewed as a code smell to use inheritance for this purpose. +1 for the first approach then

Comment: I would like to add that this only really works if you make a companion object to a normal class. With a case class, you will end up with several errors including the lack of a "tupled" method. The Scala compiler tries to access the companion object instead of the case class and requires manual tweaking. In light of this, either a standalone "common formats" object would work best, or your second approach. Honestly, the second approach seems pretty harmless compared to some of the more egregious abuses of inheritance I've seen. It just adds some extra values, not so much "methods" you'd call.

Comment: Why have a trait instead of class ?